# Back and restore for Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Does anyone know how to backup / restore an Azure AD B2C user store? I assumed that it would all be backed up and recoverable - this is Azure! - but I can't find anything in any MS documentation or the Portal.

I'm less worried about losing the B2C settings, but should disaster strike with Azure, how do I get my user data back and restore it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There is no out-of-the-box mechanism to backup your Azure AD B2C tenant**.
If your concern is "disaster striking Azure", Azure AD B2C tenants offer the [same reliability guarantees as regular Azure AD tenants](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/active-directory-whatis#how-reliable-is-azure-ad) which entails:

> The multi-tenant, geo-distributed, high availability design of Azure AD means that you can rely on it for your most critical business needs. Running out of 28 data centers around the world with automated failover, you’ll have the comfort of knowing that Azure AD is highly reliable and that even if a data center goes down, copies of your directory data are live in at least two more regionally dispersed data centers and available for instant access.

Which means that, for the most part, **you shouldn't need to back up your Azure AD B2C tenant for disaster recovery purposes.**

However if you'd still like to have backups for peace of mind, or as is the more common case, to prevent against admin/user errors:

1. You can request this feature via the [Azure AD B2C feedback forum](https://aka.ms/aadb2cuv).
2. You can, in theory, implement this yourself by periodically polling the directory for all the relevant data points (users, extension attributes, applications, groups, etc) via the Azure AD Graph as demonstrated in [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet). However this is likely to be a very cumbersome thing to set up with many gotchas (passwords can't be exported for security reasons so all users would undergo password reset, social accounts can't quite be exported yet, policies can't be exported yet either, etc...)

Comment: Really helpful and clear answer, thanks. I had a feeling that would be the case. As B2C runs an Azure AD instance under the covers, would another option be to create a separate on-site Active Directory instance and back up by sync-ing the Azure AD instance with an onsite instance?

Comment: Backup is also for human caused errors. If the resource hosting the whole b2c tenant is destroyed by mistake, or users deleted by a mistake in a piece of code that interacts with graph API the ability to roll back to yesterday's version would be helpful.