# Is there some how to backup Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I can't find an official answer for this. My researches on google say things like...

It's not necessary because Azure AD B2C is geo replicated, resilinece, bla bla bla bla bla...And even in an event of the 3rd world war, Azure AD BC2 will be up and running.

All right, nice speech, Microsoft. Very good for your sales team, but...

- We have clients. Clients are paranoids. They want us to show how we are doing the backup.
- Also, what about a clumsy admin that's accidentally deletes everyone ?
- And Azure AD B2C stores much more than user data. You can store custom user properties, App Registrations, Flows and many other things that's composes the archtecture of your solution. This must be protected as well.

So, since there is no out-of-the-box solution for this...Anyone knows something non official ? Maybe a power script or a non documented solution ? The solution at [Back and restore for Azure AD B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199745/back-and-restore-for-azure-ad-b2c) is no longer valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what about a clumsy admin that's accidentally deletes everyone ?

- You can demonstrate how you have restricted Admin access into a
  Production AAD B2C directory. You can demonstrate that you fully
  orchestrate your directory configuration through CI/CD pipelines with
  gated deployments through multiple AAD B2C tenants that act as lower
  environments.
- You have 30 days to restore all deleted objects.
- Nobody can delete all accounts via the Portal, and nor should there
  be any CI/CD pipeline built to perform such an action.

> And Azure AD B2C stores much more than user data.

1. User object - Dump users via Graph API. ObjectId can not be restored in the case of permanently deletion by an Admin.
2. Application Registrations - Config should be in a repo and controlled with CI/CD. If permanently deleted, you should demonstrate how to rebuild an App Registration using the config from your Repo, and update the Application code to reflect the new ClientId/ClientSecret. ClientId cannot be restored from a permanently deleted Application Registration.
3. User Flows - Config should be in a repo and controlled with CI/CD
4. IdP Configurations - Config should be in a repo and controlled with CI/CD
5. Custom policies - Config should be in a repo and controlled with CI/CD

Generally all features that you've configured have MS Graph API configurable endpoints that you can manage via CI/CD, and maintaining these configs in a repo.

Answer (score 0):

According to MS information [**here**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory/external-identities/b2c/#getting-started) they recommend using [**Azure Backup**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/backup/) for Azure AD B2C.  I have not tried it yet but hope to soon.